# How to register a Stored Procedure in ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I just registered a SQL Server view with ArcSDE through

```
sdetable -o register [...].
```

I wonder, how to register a SQL Server stored procedure with ArcSDE? Is it the same process as the view?

**EDIT**

It seems that to register a stored procedure, it is required to have a "stable" database object: the definition of the stored procedure by itself it is just a piece of code that has no sense until it is executed with some input parameters.

Ok, so, if we consider the stored procedure as a "data collection generator", how would you execute this code with the input parameters, catch the tabular data output and register it to ArcSDE? What would you use? Some kind of ArcGIS processing?

Please, could you provide any example or guidelines for this process?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your stored procedure return a table/view?  If not, I am not sure what SDE would do with the stored proc.  If so, an alternative would be to use your stored proc to refresh/rebuild a table or view.  It could potentially called based on a trigger or cron job.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, it returns a table with two columns: a country code and an integer. This integer is the number of points in a polygon accomplishing certain conditions (status, date...), that is why we needed a stored procedure: to calculate which ones do we need. So, how should I proceed?

Comment: I guess I should rephrase that, does it create a named table or view.  I think that you pretty much need to have a 'stable' db object, like a table or view to register it.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same: I need a stable object to be registered, the stored procedure by itself is nothing but a chunk of code. I should rephrase my question then...

Comment: I would guess that it isn't possible.  I suggest using the stored proc to create/refresh a table.  Call the stored proc via cron.

Comment: Is it possible to do your calculation in an inline function instead of a stored procedure?

Comment: Well, the stored procedure does not make "any special calculation" it just builds a dataset in function of some input parameters the user stablishes. Nothing sophisticated, though. The thing is that I need ArcGIS to access that object, but that object does not exist until I establish those input parameters, so... Anyway, I found a "workaround" with publishing all required parameters with views and filtering them later.

Comment: I think you should write up your workaround of "publishing all required parameters with views and filtering them later" as an Answer that you can then self-Accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the stored procedure does not make "any special calculation" it just builds a dataset in function of some input parameters the user stablishes. Nothing sophisticated, though. The thing is that I need ArcGIS to access that object, but that object does not exist until I establish those input parameters, so... Anyway, I found a "workaround" with publishing all required parameters with views and filtering them later